# Parse json string to find and element

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I have following json:

```
{  
   "578080":{  
      "success":true,
      "data":{  
         "price_overview":{  
            "currency":"USD",
            "initial":1799,
            "final":1799,
            "discount_percent":0
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I want to search "initial".

How can I do this using *Json.Net* or any other efficient means in C#?

**Note** : i haven't tried anything because i am unsure where to start

Comment: This has already been answered here: [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a `Dictionary<string,object>` you can follow this, [Deserialize a Dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm)

```
public class PriceOverview
{
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public int initial { get; set; }
    public int final { get; set; }
    public int discount_percent { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public PriceOverview price_overview { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, RootObject>>(json);

foreach (var result in results)
{
   Console.WriteLine(result.Key);
   Console.WriteLine(result.Value.data.price_overview.currency);
   Console.WriteLine(result.Value.data.price_overview.initial);
   Console.WriteLine(result.Value.data.price_overview.final);
   Console.WriteLine(result.Value.data.price_overview.discount_percent);

}
```

**Output**

```
578080
USD
1799
1799
0
```

---

[**Full demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qZb0KX)

Comment: Did i get something wrong? why the down votes... *looks at his code harder*